# Installation of RVM on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: rvm, ubuntu-server

I am running a VM with Ubuntu Server 12.04. 
I try to install a Ruby on Rails Application and first of all i needed to install Curl (which is done) and now i try to install RVM.

I am following this installation guide : [ruby on rails installation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm)

i am at the step when i have to run rvm to check.  But it won't load when i try to enter :

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

UPDATE :

I have this folder /usr/local/rvm

when i try to run this : `rvm requirements`

he says : the program 'rvm' is currently not installed....

but i did with this command :

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

as shown in the tutorial, or didn't it install ?  i have no errors...
i even see : thank you for using rvm!

-sh: 1: source: not found

any ideas? i am relatively new to ubuntu. thanks in advance

Comment: I believe RVM did successfully install. What action specifically is resulting in '-sh: 1: source: not found' ?

What happens when you run the following:     rvm list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as the message says:

> -sh: 1: source: not found

where `sh` is your current shell - RVM is not compatible with it, you need to use bash:

```
sudo apt-get install -y bash && sudo chsh -s $(which bash)
```

I have not tested this steps so you might slightly adjust it for your system.

Answer (score 0):

For RVM to work properly, you have to set the 'Run command as login shell' checkbox on the Title and Command tab inside of gnome-terminal's Settings page.

To do that open up a terminal by pressing CTRL+ALT+t. Once your terminal is open, right click the terminal, and click on Profiles then Profile Preferences.

Screen shot at http://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal